# How can I add to a ListView on a child form if new data is received on the main form

Tags: vb.net

I have a child form (let's call it ChildForm) that is instantiated by a parent form (MainForm). The ChildForm has a ListView control, which when initially opened populates data based on a public collection managed by the MainForm. The method within the ChildForm managing the population of the ListView is called PopulateLog and calls AddItemsToLog(logEntry). This works fine.

However, while the ChildForm is open and being displayed, the MainForm may receive additional elements, which are added to the collection. So to dynamically display the received data, I've tried the following from within the MainForm but it doesn't seem to work - nothing changes the display of the ListView in the ChildForm.

```
        If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of ChildForm).Any Then
            ChildForm.AddItemsToLog(newLogEntry)
        End If
```

I've tried ChildForm.Refresh() from within the MainForm, but also with no results.

I have searched this for a couple of hours and haven't been unable to find a clear example of how to do this - I suspect that using events/delegates is the direction to go - any help is appreciated. I suspect that this would be a useful and oft-used feature but am frustrated that it's not clearly documented.

EDIT: Also I should note that the ListViewLogReceived.Items.Count **DOES increment** when called - but the view doesn't appear to refresh. That would imply that the data is being added just not displayed. –

Comment: Is your AddItemsToLog() method public? When you say elements of your MainForm, is that a simple array? Or also Listview items?

Comment: Yes, AddItemsToLog is public.

Comment: That `If` statement and the casing of the object seems suspect.  Is `AddItemsToLog()` a *static* (I think `Shared` in VB?) method or an *instance* method?  It looks static in this usage.  Instead of looking for whether or not any forms of *type* `ChildForm` exist, you should be maintaining an actual object reference to the open instance of `ChildForm`, and calling the method on that specific instance.

Comment: Yes, AddItemsToLog is public. And yes, I process it properly the data before the call to ensure it matches the requirements for AddItemsToLog. *bold*Importantly, if I put a breakpoint on AddItemsToLog, it does break there.*bold* Here is the code fragment:'Public Sub AddItemsToLog(ByVal entry As NotificationLogEntry)
        Dim item As New ListViewItem()
        item.Text = entry.Time.ToString()
 ...
        item.Tag = entry
        ListViewLogReceived.Items.Add(item)
        item.EnsureVisible()
    End Sub'

Comment: ChildForm is an object here, not a class.  Nasty VB.NET syntax quirk.  Which completely blows up when this code runs in a thread, the likely reason you never see it.

Comment: How many column(s) by the way is/are in your `ListView` specifically in `ListViewLogReceived`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to select Hans' answer, but he led me to the right place. I was (amateurishly) referring to the class name of the form, not the instantiated version of the form. This works:

```
If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of ChildForm).Any Then
    myChildForm.AddItemsToLog(newLogEntry)
End If
```